# Showing child taxonomy terms if the parent is selected

Tags: views

I want to show one drop-down with a list of parent vocabulary terms and then when one of those select corresponding child terms displays in page.

I am using Drupal 7 with views 7.x-3.0-rc1.Any one guide me do this.

Answer (score 1):

Views doesn't have any built in way of creating an exposed filter like you explain, which means that you either need to create this functionality yourself for Views - which is very hard unless you have messed with Views APIs. The other option is to create this functionality in a custom module which a lot easier but also quite time consuming, so you will have to code it all in a custom module.

As a side note you should update your views install, currently up to date version is 3.3, This is quite important as 3.1 or 3.2 had a security fix, meaning you site has a known security vulnerability.